# I'm trying to create a save file in unity, the save and load function work, but the save file is not created

Tags: c#

So, I'm currently using C# in unity to create a save file in any operational system
using the "Application.persistentDataPath" command.

on windows 10 it's supposed to create this file in
C:\Users\User\AppData\LocalLow
thing is, it isn't creating the file.

while the application is open, the data is saved and stored, when I load, everything saved comes up

but when the application is closed and open again, the previous saved data simply doesn't exists

I'm just trying to make it create a file, and save data in it

I have tried several videos, several personal courses and I followed each and every single one of them

so far, the save function worked, but as described, no save file is created

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;


public static class SaveSystem
{
    public static BeerPiratePS beerpirateps { get; private set; }
    public static BeerPS beerps { get; private set; }
    public static BeerPubPS beerpubps { get; private set; }
    public static FactoryPS factoryps { get; private set; }
    public static GlobalBeer globalbeer { get; private set; }
    public static BeerChemistsPS beerchem { get; private set; }
    public static MainButtonClick mainbuttonclick { get; private set; }

    public static void SavePlayer ()
    {
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

        FileStream stream = File.Create(Application.persistentDataPath + "/beerplayer.ber");
        Debug.Log("BEER SAVED AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA");
        PlayerData dataPub = new PlayerData(beerpubps);
        PlayerData dataDwarves = new PlayerData(factoryps);
        PlayerData dataPirates = new PlayerData(beerpirateps);
        PlayerData dataBrew = new PlayerData(beerps);
        PlayerData dataGlobal = new PlayerData(globalbeer);
        PlayerData dataChemist = new PlayerData(beerchem);
        PlayerData dataClick = new PlayerData(mainbuttonclick);

        formatter.Serialize(stream, dataPub);
        formatter.Serialize(stream, dataPirates);
        formatter.Serialize(stream, dataDwarves);
        formatter.Serialize(stream, dataBrew);
        formatter.Serialize(stream, dataGlobal);
        formatter.Serialize(stream, dataClick);
        formatter.Serialize(stream, dataChemist);
        stream.Close();
    }
 public static PlayerData LoadPlayer()
    {
        string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/beerplayer.ber";

        if (File.Exists(path))
        {

           BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
           FileStream stream = File.Open(Application.persistentDataPath + "/beerplayer.ber", FileMode.Open);
           Debug.Log("BEER FOUND AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA");
           PlayerData dataPub = (PlayerData)formatter.Deserialize(stream) as PlayerData;
           PlayerData dataPirates = (PlayerData)formatter.Deserialize(stream) as PlayerData;
           PlayerData dataDwarves = (PlayerData)formatter.Deserialize(stream) as PlayerData;
           PlayerData dataBrew = (PlayerData)formatter.Deserialize(stream) as PlayerData;
           PlayerData dataGlobal = (PlayerData)formatter.Deserialize(stream) as PlayerData;
           PlayerData dataClick = (PlayerData)formatter.Deserialize(stream) as PlayerData;
           PlayerData dataChemist = (PlayerData)formatter.Deserialize(stream) as PlayerData;
           stream.Close();

           return dataChemist;
        }
        else
        {
           Debug.LogError("NO BEER FOUND AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA" + path);
           return null;
        }
    }
}
```

surprisingly, the logError "NO BEER FOUND AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA" hasn't appeared once

Comment: Show the loading code as well.

Comment: done, uploaded the rest of the code

Comment: Thanks, but it's preferably to do as an edit of the question, not an answer.

Comment: sorry, I'm new to StackOverflow, but here it is, fully edited

Comment: Would `Path.Combine` fix the issue? Like `File.Create(Path.Combine( Application.persistentDataPath, "beerplayer.ber"))` and `File.Open(Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "beerplayer.ber"), FileMode.Open)`

Comment: nope, I implemented the code, and the problem persisted, the file is still not being created and the data saved stops existing after the game is closed